# Trying to update 'PRAGMA user_version;' but not updating

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite

I am trying to implement a database versioning system so that I can add/remove things to the various table schemas in the future. However, I can read the database's pragma user_version, but everything I've tried to write to it has failed... I've been at this for about 2 hours, with no success. Here is where I am currently at: 
'    package statusboard.databaseHelpers;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import statusboard.Constants;

public class DataBaseHelper {

    Connection c = null;
    static Constants con = new Constants();
    static int version = -1;

    public DataBaseHelper() {
        openDatabase();
    }

    public DataBaseHelper(Connection con) {
        c = con;
    }

    public void openDatabase() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(con.getDatabaseName());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public int getDatabaseVersion() {
        // only call the SQL query if we have not already populated the version.
        if (version == -1) {
            if (c == null) {
                openDatabase();
            }
            try {
                Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
                ResultSet result;
                String sql = "PRAGMA user_version;";
                result = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                while (result.next()) {
                    version = result.getInt(1);
                }
                stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Returning version: " + version);
        return version;
    }

    public int incrementDatabaseVersion() {
        if (c == null) {
            openDatabase();
        }
        // ensure version has been populated
        if (version == 0) {
            getDatabaseVersion();
        }
        version++;
        System.out.println("new version: " + version);
        try {
            c.createStatement().execute("PRAGMA user_version =  21;");
            //stmt.execute("PRAGMA user_version = " + version);
            System.out.println("After execute");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return version;
    }

}
```

'

Constants.java of course returns a valid database.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to vacuum the SQLite database file. See what a vacuum does [here](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It ended up being that in that helper, I decided to have it establish it's own database connection. The others I had sharing a connection.... so I was getting a SQLITE database busy error. I ended up fixing this by creating a singleton in this file and calling that from the other helpers (this file is for the database directly, while the others are specific to certain tables).